# Woocommerce, вывод категорий- <pre>

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здрасьте, подскажите пожалуйста, где хранится вывод категорий в шаблонах вложенные в pre в woocommerce. Уже час бьюсь, а вывод [product_categories number="0" parent="0"] все складывает в этот pre?

```
<pre><div class="woocommerce columns-4"><ul class="">
```

Вот такое

Comment: Очень содержательный вопрос, аж даже растерялся с ответом, не могли бы вы больше информации предоставить?

Comment: Извиняюсь, уже ночь была и голова кругом. Где в файлах шаблона woocommerce содержится вывод списка категорий? Оно должно быть обернуто в pre

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос, так, чтобы все поняли, что вы хотите, пока ничего не ясно. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress/6689#6689

Comment: Вы где и как вставляете шорткод, что видите на выходе, что не так работает как ожидали?

Comment: Не может такого быть, чтоб категории было обернуты в тег pre. Прикрепите скриншот хотя бы, чтоб мы могли понять , что вы там делаете

Comment: @eugene_v написал выше во что оно оборачивает, в template ничего по woocommerce не тронуто

Comment: А что за шаблон такой, как называется?

Comment: Там не готовый шаблон, там index.php самописный и в нем вывод if (have_posts())... Все как обычно в общем. По большому счету мне надо самому сделать вывод списка категорий и заверстать его (я overrides сделал подобно джумле, скопировал из woocommerce/templates в templates/mytemplate/woocommerce

Comment: Если честно, то я так ничего и не понял.

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался, в конце самом ответ про

> If you correctly pasted your shortcodes and the display looks incorrect, make sure you did not embed the shortcode between  tags. This is a common issue. To remove these tags, edit the page, and click the Text tab

[Troubleshooting Shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/3-1-earlier/)